# Azure AD B2C Password reset flow custom layout password validation not working properly

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've created a custom layout for the "Password reset" user flow.
The password entry validation does not work properly, it does not always detect entries and when it does the information it provides is incorrect.
My layout has no custom CSS or JavaScript, it is just a plain HTML document with the div containing the value api in the id attribute inside the body.

**I worked around this issue.** I extracted CSS from the default layout provided by Microsoft.
One or some of those CSS classes did the trick, although I am not sure which of those is necessary. I wasn't able to find any information on the custom layout documentation page and that's the actual issue I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally to avoid this issue, we recommend starting with the templates, and adding your customisation on top. The templates contain a lot of the JS/CSS to control the default controls and error messaging that is part of the page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#customize-the-default-azure-ad-b2c-pages

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the templates. It would be nice if there were also more minimalistic templates available.